# changing pandas_profiling's report width size

Tags: pandas, profiling, pandas-profiling

How can I change pandas_profiling's report width size? now at jupyther lab/notebook other cells are fit to the monitor width but the pandas_profiling's report's width is narrow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `pandas_profiling` version 2 you can instruct the package to scale to the full width.

The specific code for this is:

```
df.profile_report(style={'full_width':True})
```

(or `pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(style={'full_width':True})` if you prefer)